# Matlab Plot Appearing In Small Area of Figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am having some issues with using Matlab to plot some graphs. I have using the `plot()` function but the plot produced is only taking up a fraction of the figure area.

[image]

I am unsure as to how to fix this problem, I have tried adjusting the inner and outer position but this doesn't appear to fix the problem.

The code which produces this is as above:

```
plot(brass_total(:,2), brass_total(:, 1), brass_work(:,2), brass_work(:, 1))
```

All I have done before the above code is load the values of the matrices.

Thanks

Comment: Did you call `subplot(2,2,1)` before calling plot?

Comment: I haven't used the 'subplot' function at all

Comment: Create a new figure with `figure` and *then* call `plot`

Comment: Just tried that - this is giving me the same issue for some reason.

Comment: What does `get(0, 'defaultaxesposition')` give you?

Comment: This returns the following : `ans =

    0.1300    0.1100    0.7750    0.8150 `

Comment: Can you show us the code that causes this?

Comment: Does this happen if you relaunch MATLAB? Alternately, close all figures `close all` and try again

Comment: Just reclosing matlab and reopening it appears to have fixed it! Thanks! Any idea what the problem was?

Comment: I have no idea apart from *something* maybe called `subplot` and then you continued to reuse that `axes` when plotting new data.

Comment: A guess: You're using OS X and a Retina MacBook connected to a main non-Retina external monitor? I get this behavior when I disconnect from the monitor and Matlab switches to use only the Retina display. Only fix I've found is to restart Matlab. If this is the same for you, i t's clearly a bug so you might consider reporting it to The MathWorks by [filing a service request](https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/index.html).